# select only Values based on previous value

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2008

I want to populate a  table with SSIS . When  a status column has 'cancellation', I only want to populate It only if it  also has another row with same ID and the status column is  "New sale" . I already have some rows with `'New sales'` and also has its 'cancellations' for the same Id (Which I also want to populate) on my source Table . so I can't  use a where Clause `(where status = 'New Sale')`. I don't want to populate IDs without prior `'New Sale'`

Comment: How about some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really hard to answer with precision because there is so little information available. We don't know the table name or the column names (except perhaps "status") and we also don't have any examples to look at. So, a solution might be to use EXISTS

```
select t1.*
from yourtable t1
where exists (
   select NULL
   from yourtable t2
   where t1.orderid = t2.orderid
   and (t1.status = 'cancelled' and t2.status = 'New sales'
     or t2.status = 'cancelled' and t1.status = 'New sales')
   )
and t1.status IN('cancelled','New sales')
```